# Methods referring to Deeply Nested Object in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, scope, vue.js

For the global data I have to implement an array of objects.
Which i made an elementary prototype called newDevis.
(sorry for the mixture between french words and english ^^)
This also contains two arrays of objects

devisPieces and devisMainOeuvres which are filled with prototype arrays called

devisPiece and devisMainOeuvre

and then i have a method using these two arrays' data to make a sum of them which i will use later.

the problem is that I'm always getting the "newDevis" is undefined.

so here is the global vue app
PS: you may wonder why not call the app to do its action directly into newDevis and newFacture:
well I wanted to make a common function (because basically thet do the same job but for different goals) and depending on the string you pass ("devis" or "facture") it makes necessary action to the specified data.

```js
{
var standard = new Vue({
    el: '#standard',
    data() {
        return {
            /*more Data*/
            //Prototypes Data
            
            //Devis Facture
                newDevis: {
                    codeDevis: '', dateDevis: '', nombrePieces: 0, sousTotal: 0, totalRemise: 0,
                    totalHT: 0, fodec: 0, totalTaxes: 0, timbreFiscal: 0, totalTTC: 0,
                    devisPieces: [], devisMainOeuvres: []
                },
                devisPiece: { nomPiece: '', quantite: 0, prixUnitaire: 0, tva: 0, remise: 0 },
                devisMainOeuvre: { libelleMainOeuvre: '', nombreHeure: 0, prixUnitaire: 0, remise: 0 },
                //Facture vars
                newFacture: {
                    codeFacture: '', dateFacture: '', nombrePieces: 0, sousTotal: 0, totalRemise: 0,
                    totalHT: 0, fodec: 0, totalTaxes: 0, timbreFiscal: 0, totalTTC: 0,
                    facturePieces: [], factureMainOeuvres: []
                },
                facturePiece: { nomPiece: '', quantite: 0, prixUnitaire: 0, tva: 0, remise: 0 },
                factureMainOeuvre: { libelleMainOeuvre: '', nombreHeure: 0, prixUnitaire: 0, remise: 0 },
            
            //fictive data                
        }
    }
    , watch: {
    },
    methods: {
        // Devis et Facture
        calculQuantiteFlouss(flouss) {
            self = this;
            Flouss = self.capitalize(flouss);
            nameDevis = "new" + Flouss;
            devisName1 = flouss + "Pieces";
            devisName2 = flouss + "MainOeuvre";                   
            var quantitePieces = 0;
            function sumPieces(flouss) {
                if (!isNaN([eval(flouss)].quantite)) {
                    quantitePieces += +[eval(flouss)].quantite;
                }
                if (!isNaN([eval(flouss)].nombreHeure)) {
                    quantitePieces += +[eval(flouss)].nombreHeure;
                }
            };
            console.log(self[eval(nameDevis)]);//to check its type
            self[eval(nameDevis)][eval(devisName1)].foreach(sumPieces);
            self[eval(nameDevis)][eval(devisName2)].foreach(sumPieces);
            return self[eval(nameDevis)].quantite = quantitePieces;
        },
    },
    computed: {
    },
    mounted() {
    }
})
}
```

I feel like it's a scope problem but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet that is actually working somehow? The template would be nice.

Comment: actually the complete template is nothing but a dozen of inputs that fills the devisPiece and devisMainOeuvre arrays which are appended into the newDevis and then the return of this method is put into a span. so if you do need it i'll provide it in a couple of minutes.
big thanks for you :)

Comment: I don't think you want those `eval`s. The values are just strings.

Comment: thanks @roy J but already i tried that also it didn't work